# Convert string to JS object

Tags: javascript, audio, buzz.js

I know its a repeated questions but I cannot figure out how to do in my case.
I want to play audio using JS Buzz library. Please check following

```
var pg1 = new buzz.sound("oimages/music/as.mp3");
var pg2 = new buzz.sound("oimages/music/zx.mp3");
var pg3 = new buzz.sound("oimages/music/as.mp3");
```

On a certain event I want to play this audio. here 1, 2 and 3 are page numbers. Please check following

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turned", function (event, page, view) {;
    bog ='pg'+page; // page is the number of page here
    window.bog.play(); //error
});
```

It gives me following error

> Uncaught TypeError: window.bog.play is not a function

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `bog ='pg'+page;` is a string, not a reference to the sound file.

You need to reference the sound assuming they are in global scope you can use bracket notation

```
var bog = window['pg'+page];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake.  You're trying to reference the variable incorrectly.  `bog` isn't the name, but it contains the name...

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turned", function (event, page, view) {;
    bog ='pg'+page; // page is the number of page here
    window[bog]play(); //error
});
```

This assumes that the `pg1..3` variables have global scope.  If they don't then change the declarations to...

```
window.pg1 = new buzz.sound("oimages/music/as.mp3");
```

etc..

Answer (score -1):

Evaluating would do the trick:

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turned", function (event, page, view) {;
    bog ='pg'+page;
    eval('window.' + bog + '.play()');
});
```